# Intuit API throwing "Required parameter ExpenseAccountRef or IncomeAccountRef is missing in the request" for non inventory item

Tags: c#, asp.net, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am attempting to create an item on QuickBooks Online using Intuits IPP SDK V3.0 for ASP.net. I have set the only parameter to the Intuit.Ipp.Data.Item() to be a name and am receiving a validation error stating "Required parameter ExpenseAccountRef or IncomeAccountRef is missing in the request" I have even specified that it is not an inventory item by setting item.TypeSpecified = false; but still get the error response.

```
var success=true;
try{
   var item = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Item();
   item.Name = thisItem.name;
   item.TypeSpecified = false;
   var resultItem = service.Add(item) as Intuit.Ipp.Data.Item;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   var problem = e.ToString();
   success = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid error-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Item

Check the business rules.
Even on the company file, adding an account is mandatory for the item even when it is non-inventory/service
Create an item

The item name must be unique.
Sales items must have IncomeAccountRef.
Purchase items must have ExpenseAccountRef.

Comment: Are there any "items" that are neither a Sales or Purchase item?

Comment: No. There aren't any.